# Postgresql terminate queries if it run more than 20 mins

Tags: sql, postgresql

Usually my query is running more than 20 mins. Once it reach 20 mins it is automatically terminated by postgresql terminal. Then i run my query in ssh server.

Can any one suggest me what are the steps i supposed to do while running my query in postgresql terminal?

Note:I am retrieving  more than 5 million data.

Comment: Post your query.

Comment: Is statement_timeout set to 20 minutes?  To check this: SHOW statement_timeout;

Comment: Also, check if you have an overzealous firewall in between. If yes, reduce `tcp_keepalives_idle` on the database server.